# Image source value - a combination of hardcoded strings and binding

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, data-binding

I have an image in my xaml:

```
<Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="30" Height="30"></Image>
```

The source for the image is like this:

```
..\Images\MyFolder\1.png
..\Images\MyFolder\2.png
..\Images\MyFolder\3.png
```

Basically, the name of the .png file is the id of the items.

In my ViewModel I have a field which represents the id, its name is myId.

How do I add this kind of source - with two hardcoded values and one binding value?

Comment: Either by another view model property that returns the image path, or by an appropriate binding converter, that converts your ID to an image path string, or URI, or ImageSource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the Image source with the id and apply a converter to create the image path.

The xaml will be:

```
ente<Image Source="{Binding Path=myId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ConvImageSource}}"/>
```

And add the resouce at the top:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ImageSourceConverter x:Key="ConvImageSource"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

And the converter can be:

```
public class ImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{        
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        String myId = System.Convert.ToString(value);
        String imagePath = SPECIFY_IMAGE_PATH;
        String imageExtn = SPECIFY_IMAGE_Extn;

        // Create the image source
        String imageSource = String.Concat(imagePath, myId, imageExtn);

        return imageSource;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I get the error: {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSourceConverter' to type 'System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter'."}

Comment: Put a break point at the `ConvertBack`; if you are geting the exception here, then you need to implement your `ConvertBack` according to the requirement.

Comment: Convert and ConvertBack aren't even hit.